# ERROR: User lacks privilege or object not found HSQLDB

Tags: java, database, jsp, jdbc, hsqldb

Hello I'm using HSQLDB and craeted a table `EMPLOYEE` with the attribute `ID`. The db is a standalone db and here is the script file for it:

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB56BCF1778F
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 32
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
CREATE USER "Chris" PASSWORD DIGEST '4a7d1ed414474e4033ac29ccb8653d9b'
ALTER USER "Chris" SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID VARCHAR(20))
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO "Chris"
SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('CHRIS')
```

I use this java class to access the db:

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * Dies Klasse liefert eine  JDBC Connection zurück
 * @author Christian
 *
 */
public class JDBCConnector {

    private Connection connection;

    public JDBCConnector(String url, String user, String password){
        try{
          Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
          if(connection != null){
              System.out.println("Verbindung hergestellt");
          }
        }catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ){
            System.err.println("Der Datenbanktreiber konnte nicht geladen werden");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Beim Erstellen der Verbindung ist ein Feheler aufgetreten.\n"
                    + "Bitte überprüfen Sie die URL, sowie Usernamen und Passwort");
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
        if(connection != null){
            return connection;
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Connection == null");
        }
    } 

    public String getFirstEntry(){
        try {
            Statement stmt;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;");
            rs.next();
            String s = rs.getString(1);
            connection.close();
            return s;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }


}
```

It's only a test class so ....

And here I call the function from a jsp file:

```
<% JDBCConnector connector = new JDBCConnector("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/Gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_Full/WebContent/gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_full/server/db/DB2;shutdown=true", "Chris", "0000"); 
out.append(connector.getFirstEntry());
%>
```

So got some one a solution? In the past this error occured, because I've forgot `shutdown=true` but this time, I got no idea... The table name is 100% correct.

Comment: Unrelated but: you should **not** initiate JDBC connections inside a JSP page. Use a proper connection pool in your container and do the database work in a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to the database using a relative (to base) path. This path resolves to different locations in different execution contexts such as JSP.

During development, use the `ifexists=true` connection property to avoid creating and connecting to a new database. Put the existing database where the path points to in the execution context.

```
<% JDBCConnector connector = new JDBCConnector("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/Gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_Full/WebContent/gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_full/server/db/DB2;shutdown=true;ifexists=true", "Chris", "0000"); 
out.append(connector.getFirstEntry());
%>
```

The `shutdown=true` property is useful for testing. If your connection lasts a long time, it is also fine for production. But if you are closing the connection regularly, it repeatedly shuts down the database. In this case, you can consider the alternative, `hsqldb.write_delay=false`. See the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_connection_props

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_cache_persistence

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I've got still the same error. I think, because I want to use a standalone db in a webapp...because when I have the same classes inn a normal java project, everything works fine.

Comment: You can use a standalone db in a web app. You must use either an absolute file path or a variable that points to the root of the web server files directory where you keep the database. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_variables_url

Comment: The path is correct I think. Because, when I put the link "http://localhost:8080/Test_Full/Test_full/server/db/db.script", I see the script of the HSQLDB with the correkt entries. So at the moment, I've got really no answer to this problem :/

Comment: I've realized, that with an local instnace it works. But I would like to have a file because, it's for a presantation in school

Comment: Your database path is not pointing to the location of the database files. Your test is actually demonstrating this, because you've put the files among the web pages. Search the web server directory structure and find the wrong database files, then copy your database to this location.

Comment: Thank you :) But when I give it "jdbc:hsqldb:file:db" or "jdbc:hsqldb:file:/db", the db is saved under "C:\"

Comment: The web app has created and is pointing to a different database file. Find where this file is located then copy your database to this location.